# How can I display the value of an HTTP variable, like HTTP_ACCEPT?

Tags: apache

I'm running Apache 2.4 and I'd like to see the values being received for some HTTP variables, like HTTP_ACCEPT.   Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CustomLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog), which allows logging of anything that can expressed in a [custom log format](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats), including `%{VARNAME}i` to log HTTP headers:

> **%{VARNAME}i**
>
> The contents of VARNAME: header line(s) in the request sent to the server. Changes made by other modules (e.g. mod_headers) affect this. If you're interested in what the request header was prior to when most modules would have modified it, use mod_setenvif to copy the header into an internal environment variable and log that value with the %{VARNAME}e described above.